How to Unit test side effects of individual components
I am writing unit tests for my Lit.js plugin application. I have created a root custom component, that renders either regular HTML elements or custom elements.
I did set up Webdriver.io with Mocha for the unit tests, however my question is broader i.e. how do I test e.g. the following:

I have a component called "PlayerInactive" which is basically a button wrapped in a div. On that button click I am sending a custom event to the parent component which is handled there and toggle its state true/false.

When writing the unit test I have only appended the PlayerInactive to DOM so if I try to test this event and wheter is working, it won't actually do anything rather then emit this event.
Should I just test to see if this event was emitted and would that be considered a unit test?
How would I then go about actually testing whether it would toggle the parent component. Would I write like a global test for the parent component that tests interactions between each element?

I think there's room for subjectivity here. I would technically consider a unit test for PlayerInactive component to just include whether the event fired and that's it. If the logic for what triggers that is not straight forward, maybe that warrants the unit test. Otherwise an integration test with the parent by rendering both and testing behavior might give you more confidence.
